# Is there a Linux distro (à la Open/DD WRT) for smart speakers?

Tags: amazon-echo, google-home, linux, apple-homepod

[Smart speakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_speaker) like Amazon Echo or Google Home are starting to become common. Is there a community effort to create an open source Linux firmware that can be run on them? I am thinking to something like Openwrt and Dd-wrt for routers.

A Google search returned nothing relevant, but it is strange that no one ever considered this idea yet (especially given the many privacy issues in their default firmware).

Comment: Using an off-the-shelf Linux to make a custom smart speaker would be a very distinct thing from getting a custom Linux running on an existing smart speaker.  Pretty much sure everything you need to turn a documented hardware platform into one is available - certainly if you use a pi, *probably* for various OpenWRT platforms.

Comment: @ChrisStratton So you're saying that this hasn't been attempted because it's a lot easier to make a homebrew smart speaker from scratch using a Raspberry Pi and some audio circuitry, rather than hacking an (undocumented) commercial one like an Amazon Echo/Google Home? This makes sense, I agree.